# Webpack working only on first build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm using Webpack to build my React project, but I'm experiencing an issue.
When I delete the build folder and let webpack build it again, my code works, but when webpack rebuild it because of the watch option, it doesn't work. I get those errors in my JS console:

- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null(anonymous function) @ VM3739:5(anonymous function) @ VM3739:20
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Here is my webpack config file:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = [{
    entry: './src/app/App.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'build/app.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }

            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('build/style.css', {
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            },
            output: {
                comments: false
            }
        })
    ],
    watchOptions: {
        poll: 1000
    }
}];
```

Comment: what version of webpack do you use?

Comment: The last one: 1.13